# Counting occurrences using filter and reduce in Python

Tags: python, filter, reduce

```
c=["pink", "purple", "black", "yellow", "purple", "indego", "white", "peach"]
import random
import collections
def apply(T):
    i = random.randint(0, 7)
    return c[i]
for x in range(1, 50):
    for ch in map(apply, c):
        print(ch)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to count the occurrences of each of the numbers by only using the filter and reduce functions.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

EDIT: FOR CLARIFICATION, I want to count the amount of times a random number of a certain type is generated, not the one in the list!

Comment: Could you give us the expected output?

Comment: Use a `collections.Counter`.  Would you use a screwdriver to drive in a nail?

Comment: Unfortunatly I need to use Filter and Reduce, hence why I'm struggling.

an expected output would be a count of each of the colours declaring how many times it appeared.

Comment: I'm confused.  What are you counting here?  Is it just the list `c`?  How does the function `apply` and the import of `random` have anything to do with anything ...

Comment: @wim -- Probably because some professor somewhere is trying to teach them functional programming ...

Comment: I'm attempting to count the number of times a colour is outputted NOT the amount of them in the list!

Answer (score 3):

First off, your `apply` function ignores its argument, which is never a good sign for something you're giving to `map`. I'm going to assume you were trying to generate a list of random colors, called `colors`, and then count that; you could equally well replace that by a generator.

Filter, reduce, etc are functional programming concepts that are usually better handled via list comprehensions or generators in Python. Here's how I'd do it:

```
c = ["pink", "purple", "black", "yellow", "purple", "indego", "white", "peach"]

import random
colors = [c[random.randrange(len(c))] for _ in range(50)]

# now, to count

# (a) the way you'd actually do it in practice:
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(colors)

# (b) the way you'd actually do it without the collections module
counts = {}
for x in colors:
    if x not in counts:
        counts[x] = 0
    counts[x] += 1

# (c) doing it with reduce...technically.
def add_to_counter(counter, el):
    counter[el] += 1  # can't actually do this in a lambda...
counts = reduce(add_to_counter, colors, Counter())
```

You could also do something similar to (c) but without just using the Counter class by maintaing a list of elements and their counts, and adding to them in the reduce function, but that's just a less efficient and more cumbersome version of the same thing.

Since you say you *have* to use filter and reduce, I'm assuming this is a homework assignment. This is silly, because those are absolutely the wrong tools for this problem. But here's a horribly inefficient and unreadable way to use filter and reduce (and map, too) to solve this problem, which is probably like what your instructor is looking for:

```
from functools import partial
import operator
counts = {}
for x in c:
    counts[x] = reduce(operator.add,
                       map(lambda _: 1, filter(partial(operator.eq, x), colors)),
                       0)
```

This is horrible because:

- It takes a lot of effort to figure out what's going on, instead of the obviousness of (a) and (b) above.
- You should *always* use `sum` in Python rather than `reduce(operator.add, ...)`.
- So,  `counts[x] = sum(1 for el in colors if el == x)` is the same (bad) algorithm but a million times more readable and much shorter to boot.
- Even so, the `reduce`/`sum` and `map` could just be replaced by a call to `len(filter(...))` (assuming Python 2; in three, `filter` returns an iterator and so you'd have to do `len(list(filter(...)))`, which is wasteful).
- It passes over the full `colors` list one time for each color, rather than just once. This makes it impossible to use in cases where you don't know the full list of possible outcomes, and much less efficient in all cases.

The only possible "advantage" someone could claim is that it includes 0 counts for any colors that don't appear. This is of course trivial to do with any of the other solutions as well.

Comment: @wim I wasn't, because there's no need to do so. But my edit now uses it.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3.0, but out of curiosity how would I of used the len method?

Comment: In Python 2, `filter` returns a list, which you can just take the `len` of to see how many elements there are. In 3, it returns an iterator, which doesn't have a direct length; `sum(1 for x in the_iterator)`, which is basically what we're doing here, accomplishes more or less the same thing.

Comment: count = {color: len(filter(lambda x: x == color, c)) for color in set(c)}
print count

So in the case of the above code how would I get that to output for 3.3.0?

Comment: That code, or any of the code in my answer, creates a dictionary with keys as the color name and output the count. To print it out, either just do `print(counts)` or something like `for color, count in counts.iteritems(): print("{}: {}".format(color, count))`.

Comment: I was understanding the difference between using a Len and Using a Sum, the above code achieved what I needed but Python didn't like me using a Len on a filter.

Comment: Yes - as I said earlier, you'd use `sum(1 for x in filter(lambda x: x == color, c))`, or much preferably `sum(1 for x in c if x == color)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Dougal

Below works fine to count the list using reduce and lambda:

```
    c = ["pink", "purple", "black", "yellow", "purple", "indego", "white", "peach", "test"]
    print reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1, c, 0)
```

Notice that last parameter to reduce() which is 0.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will be the simplest solution. It does not use filters or so, but it seems quite smart solution

```
counts = [(colors.count(x), x) for x in set(colors)]
```

You can also make a dict, not list of tuples... depending on python interpreter version you use.

Comment: This does #colors + 1 passes over the list, just like the version with reduce/filter at the end of my answer. Using a Counter/dict is at least as easy to understand and substantially superior in terms of runtime.

Comment: it takes 2 or 3 times less code... and this way is more elegant I guess... kinda pythonic way

Comment: I'd take pretty strong issue with saying the "pythonic way" is the way with an equal amount of code that's no easier to understand and a large amount slower. Additionally, your way only works on a list input, where `Counter` or doing it manually with a dictionary works on an iterator. Your call to `set(colors)` is _already doing all the work_ you need to do except for adding 1!